# Chain of div elements following a mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, graphics

I'm trying to make a sort of snake consisting of HTML divs that follow the mouse inside a specific area.

I have a pretty good result with the first one, but now I'm having problems figuring out how to make the second div follow the first one:

https://jsbin.com/xozawokore/edit?js,output

I would like to build a function that takes as input a div and another div to follow.

If someone can suggest a way to do this or improve the existing code (the first div follows mouse quite well right now, but is not perfect yet), it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to approach this task is to apply a function `follow(snake, leader)` to each consecutive pair of snake segments such that `snake` is behind `leader`.

If each snake segment has properties `x` and `y` that store the position of the segment's center, you can calculate the distance and angle of displacement between the segments:

```
var dx = leader.x - snake.x,
    dy = leader.y - snake.y,
    dd = Math.hypot(dx, dy),
    angle = snake.angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
```

Now you can adjust `snake.x` and `snake.y` in the direction `angle` so that the follower moves closer to the leader.

The head segment can follow an object that you define as `{ x: mouseX, y: mouseX }` and that you update with the mouse position whenever it changes.

The following snippet demonstrates this approach.

```js
function rotate(element, radians) {
  radians += Math.PI / 2;
  var s = 'rotate(' + radians + 'rad)';
  $(element).css('-moz-transform', s)
      .css('-webkit-transform', s)
      .css('-o-transform', s)
      .css('-ms-transform', s);
}

function initSnakes(container, numSnakes) {
  var snakeWidth = 22,
      snakeHeight = 22,
      snakeRadius = Math.max(snakeWidth, snakeHeight),
      maxDistance = 1.5 * snakeRadius,
      frameRate = 60,
      damping = 9 * frameRate / 30,
      width = container.width(),
      height = container.height(),
      border = parseInt(container.css('border-left-width'), 10),
      left = container.offset().left + border,
      top = container.offset().top + border,
      snakes = new Array(numSnakes),
      mouse = { x: width / 5, y: height / 5, mouse: true };

  function positionSnake(snake) {
    $(snake.element).css({ left: snake.x - snakeWidth / 2,
        top: snake.y - snakeHeight / 2 });
    rotate(snake.element, snake.angle);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < numSnakes; ++i) {
    var snake = snakes[i] = {
      id: i,
      x: width * 4 / 5,
      y: height * 4 / 5,
      angle: Math.PI * 3 / 2,
      element: $.parseHTML('<div class="snakeSegment"></div>')
    };
    var color = 'rgb(90, 150, ' + Math.min(200, (120 + 35 * i)) + ')';
    $(snake.element).css('border-bottom-color', color);
    container.append(snake.element);
    positionSnake(snake);
    if (i == 0) {
      follow(snake, mouse);
    } else {
      follow(snake, snakes[i - 1]);
    }
  }

  function follow(snake, leader) {
    function update () {
      var dx = leader.x - snake.x,
          dy = leader.y - snake.y,
          dd = Math.hypot(dx, dy),
          angle = snake.angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx),
          direction = (dd < snakeRadius ? -1 : 1);
      if (dd > maxDistance && !leader.mouse) {
        snake.x += Math.cos(angle) * (dd - maxDistance);
        snake.y += Math.sin(angle) * (dd - maxDistance);
        dx = leader.x - snake.x;
        dy = leader.y - snake.y;
        dd = maxDistance;
      }
      if (dd - snakeRadius < 0.5) {
        return;
      }
      snake.x += direction * Math.cos(angle) * dd / damping;
      snake.y += direction * Math.sin(angle) * dd / damping;
      positionSnake(snake);
    }
    update();
    snake.moveInterval = window.setInterval(update, 1000 / frameRate);
  }

  function mouseUpdate(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    mouse.x = event.pageX - left;
    mouse.y = event.pageY - top;
  }
  container.mousemove(mouseUpdate);
}

function launch() {
  initSnakes($('#snakeShadowDemo'), 5);
}

$(document).ready(launch);

$(window).resize(function () {
  $('.snakeSegment').remove();
  launch();
});
```

```css
.snakeSegment {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 11px solid transparent;
  border-right: 11px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 22px solid #333;
}

#snakeShadowDemo {
  width: 400px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: solid 3px #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

<div id="snakeShadowDemo"></div>
```

Comment: Great! that's what I'm trying to do... One last thing: while you were writing this wonderful example, I was trying to figure out how to constrain max distance between snake parts (to avoid them become too far the ones from each others while moving the mouse quickly); since your example works better than mine, maybe you know a better solution also for this...

Comment: I've added a variable called `maxDistance`. You can adjust it to your liking. Currently it applies only between snake elements, not between the mouse and the snake's head. If you do want the snake to follow the mouse closely, delete `mouse: true` from the first call to `follow`.

Comment: Perfect! You did all the work for me ;) I was just comparing your solution with the one I was working on, and yours is far better, so I will keep it; thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Each div should have a unique id starting with 0 (or 1). Then

```
numDivs;
var firstDiv = document.getElementById("0");
firstDiv.setCoordinates(mouse.x, mouse.y); // this isnt correct but you get the idea
previousDiv = firstDiv;
for(var i = 1; i < numDivs; i ++){
    var div = document.getElementById(i);
    div.setCoordinates(previousDiv.x + offset, previousDiv.y + offset); // sequentially set the coordinates based upon the previous div
    previousDiv = div;
}
```

Comment: interesting, and what about rotation?

Comment: I havent actually looked at how you are applying the orientation/position etc. You will have to do the math yourself but the basic idea is that you base each successive triangle off the previous one starting with the mouse pointer at the root.

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/avp1p8nq/)***

I would suggest creating an array to hold these divs. In this simple demo I have named them orbs (as they are yellow circles). Each time the mouse moves, an orb is created. If there are more than 5 orbs, the first one in the array is removed (shift() removes the first item from an array).

There is a call to `orb()` which could be easily modified to any sort of div in this situation. There is also a small amount of collision detection involved with the side of the mouse area (document).

```js
(function(){
 var orbs = [];
 function orb(){
  return $('<div class="yellowOrb">')[0]; 
 }
 window.onmousemove = function(e){
  var docH = $(document).height(),
      docW = $(document).width();
  if( e.pageY < 5 || e.pageY > (docH-40)
     || e.pageX < 5 || e.pageX > (docW-40) ) {
      $(orbs).each(function(){
          $(orbs.shift()).remove();  
      });
      return;
  }
  var ylow = orb();
  ylow.style.top = e.pageY-50 + "px";
  ylow.style.left = e.pageX-50 + "px";
  orbs.push(ylow);
  if(orbs.length > 5){
      $(orbs.shift()).remove();
  }
  $('body').append(ylow);
 };
})()
```

```css
.yellowOrb{ 
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    opacity: 0.75;
    border-radius:100px;
    pointer-events:none;
    z-index:99999
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you for suggestions;
I've rewrited it using an array of circles (so no rotation to handle for now);

https://jsbin.com/zenowoduxu/edit?js,output

now I'll try with triangles and rotation...